# C# Passing a variable to a new instance of a class

Tags: c#, class, constructor

I have the following problem ...
in my HomeController of my C# Razor WebApp I call a new instance of the class DBHandler, how can I pass here variables from the HomeController or the values from it to the new instance of the other class? I'm sure this is simple, but I'm stuck right now and not getting anywhere.

**Controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
  public string myUserName = "Michael";
  public string myPass = "PassWord";

  privarte DBHandler dbhandler = new DBHandler();

  ....
}
```

**DBHandler**

```
public class DBHandler
{ 
  string conString = "Conn;Database=DB;User ID=" + myUserName + ";Password=" + myPass + 
  "...";

  .....
}
```

How can I pass my variables myUserName/myPass to the instance of DBHandler or query it from the class? I need this to login to the database with different users.

Manny thanks in advance,
Michael

Comment: it's curious because you used the `constructor` tag in your question.. did you try to just have a constructor for your DBHandler class?

Comment: yeah, I agreed with @DiegoD

Comment: Hi volks, I have succeeded ... thanks to Mathias.

Comment: @Michael7, if my answer helped you to solve your problem then do not forget to accept it by clicking on ✔

Answer (score 0):

You can create a parameterized constructor in DBHandle class and pass values while creating an instance

Create Parameterized [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors):

```
public class DBHandler
{ 
  public string UserName { get; set; }
  public string Password { get; set; }
  public string ConString { get; set; }
  public DBHandler(string username, string password)
  {
     
     this.UserName = username;
     this.Password = password;
     this.ConString = "Conn;Database=DB;User ID=" + myUserName + ";Password=" + myPass;
  }
}
```

Now pass values while creating an instance,

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
  public string myUserName = "Michael";
  public string myPass = "PassWord";

  privarte DBHandler dbhandler = new DBHandler(myUserName, myPass);

  ....
}
```